# Minimum requirements to get xawtv to work?

Tags: pulseaudio

I've recently been given the task of converting a stack of ancient home videos on vcr video tapes to digital data.  I managed to scrounge up an old vcr, connect it to an old "tevion" (em2820) video capture device I found somewhere, hook it up to my Linux box, and after installing xawtv, it actually worked!

Video, that is; no sound.

I thought I was just a step or two away from retrieving all the data on these tapes, but after hours and hours of research, it seems to come down to this: xawtv is too old to use PulseAudio, and is no longer being updated, and therefore will never support audio on modern Linux systems.  And, composite video capture systems are too old to be supported by modern multimedia software, and therefore can only be used with programs like xawtv.

I think my next option is to sacrifice one of my old PCs and install an old enough version of Linux (Ubuntu or otherwise) such that xawtv can run without issue.  Is there an easy way to determine the most recent Ubuntu that could run without PulseAudio?  Or perhaps some other distribution is more friendly to really old software?  Thanks!

EDIT: I didn't need to go to an older distribution of Linux.  It turns out ffmpeg can, in fact, access the video capture device (via v4l2), and capture the audio input (piping it into the line-in port and using "alsa"), and then combining the two together.  I don't have a perfect set of command options yet, but this does the basics:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -thread_queue_size 1024 -i hw:0,0 -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -video_size 720x480 -framerate ntsc -i /dev/video0 -f avi test.avi
```

Comment: The package `xawtv` is still in current repositories (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xawtv) so I'd expect it to work; you just may need to setup ALSA (advanced linux sound architecture which predated pulseaudio).   I don't know anything helpful, however I'd try Ubuntu-Studio myself (https://ubuntustudio.org/about-ubuntustudio/)

Comment: Thanks, @guiverc!  Sadly, that doesn't seem to be the case; there really is some issue between 'xawtv' and PulseAudio.  Here's a similar Redhat bugzilla [entry](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1090652) involving the same issue.  I see that ubuntu studio uses ffmpeg; I don't think I tried that with my capture device hardware yet, I'll give it a try...

Comment: To my knowledge Lubuntu 16.04 LTS was the last Ubuntu that didn't include pulse audio; which is now EOL though the base being Ubuntu is still supported (just not the gui packages).  Please note this is from memory; I recall problems with firefox no longer playing videos because it didn't work without pulseaudio which was a problem with Lubuntu 16.04 at one time (the other flavors all use pulseaudio). *Any other answers would be 14.04 or off-topic for this site as only supported Ubuntu releases are on-topic here*

Comment: Tried Lubuntu 16.04, but still couldn't get xawtv to work correctly.   However, I did bite the bullet and started to dig in to ffmpeg; after a few hours of wrapping my head around the system, I have finally managed to get it to access both the video and the audio, and combine them together!  The quality is terrible so far, but that should improve after a few days (weeks?) of figuring out how to tweak ffmpeg.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 16.04 LTS was the last Ubuntu flavor to not include Pulse Audio by default. Please note Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL; whilst the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS base is still supported the GUI & packages reached the end of their three years of supported life earlier this year.

I recall this as when Firefox 52 came out, it was without audio on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS but fine on other 16.04 flavors.  Firefox put it's audio out thru PulseAudio unless a `--disable-pulseaudio --enable-alsa` option was used at compile time necessary only for the Lubuntu 16.04 LTS flavor.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try.

Comment: I was unable to get xawtv to work in Lubuntu 16.04, with the same error -- it was unable to access the audio system.  At this point, I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I still think Ubuntu-Studio is your best bet as stated in first comment.  Being a audio/visual creation specific flavor of Ubuntu, they've had to pre-setup ALSA to make it work where users of the other flavors have no need, and have documented ffmpeg & like tools somewhat as its something their users do use. Non-Ubuntu's are off-topic on this site, as are unsupported releases (SE's Unix & Linux doesn't have those rules for example..)

Comment: I see.  I'll check it out; but, if as you say, there is no solution to getting xawtv to work with ubuntu (at least none that are on topic), I think I should probably mark my original question as unsolvable.  Xawtv should probably be declared as obsolete and unusable within ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

I use `xawtv` since 20 years without major problems.
On `pulseaudio` systems (16.04) I use `pasdp` as wrapper to emulate OSS sound devices, e.g.:

```
padsp xawtv $* -geometry 768x576 -nodga
```

`-nodga` is needed as `dga` support is dropped since some x11 releases, the `geometry` is for PAL video.
You can record `mjpeg avi` files with audio and process them in other programs.